# Unable to add CA cert [crt] to JKS as PrivateKeyEntry

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

Below is my current JKS

```
bash-3.2$ keytool -list -keystore /web/myfolder/maincert.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

root, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 02:FA:F3:E2:91:43:54:68:60:78:57:69:4D:F5:E4:5B:68:85:18:68
maincert, Aug 1, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): A0:BF:8A:61:D7:AE:82:A6:EE:4B:EB:E0:22:19:73:2E:FC:85:F8:AC
intermediate2, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 70:60:8B:40:D0:B7:76:17:4A:4E:D8:54:16:58:27:70:B3:07:B9:05
intermediate1, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): EA:B0:40:68:9A:0D:80:5B:5D:6F:D6:54:FC:16:8C:FF:00:B7:8B:E3
```

I then deleted the "maincert" using this command

```
keytool -delete -alias maincert -keystore /web/myfolder/maincert.jks
```

Then i added the CA signed new cert [maincert.crt_2018] with the same old alias name as shown below:

```
keytool -import -file /web/myfolder/maincert.crt_2018 -alias maincert -keystore /web/myfolder/maincert.jks
```

But the new cert now shows as trusted entry in the JKS instead of PrivateKeyEntry like before. Please see below:

```
bash-3.2$ keytool -list -keystore /web/myfolder/maincert.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

root, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 02:FA:F3:E2:91:43:54:68:60:78:57:69:4D:F5:E4:5B:68:85:18:68
maincert, Aug 28, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): D2:7F:D0:86:79:0D:F3:06:66:C4:09:2E:29:A0:8F:8A:F3:E2:09:10
intermediate2, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 70:60:8B:40:D0:B7:76:17:4A:4E:D8:54:16:58:27:70:B3:07:B9:05
intermediate1, Aug 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): EA:B0:40:68:9A:0D:80:5B:5D:6F:D6:54:FC:16:8C:FF:00:B7:8B:E3
```

Can you please suggest what is the problem here ?

Comment: You deleted the private key. What did you expect would happen?

Comment: If I don't fire the keytool -delete command and simply import then I get the this error: keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.io.IOException: Short read of DER length

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the crt certificate file was corrupt.

With the correct crt I did not have to delete anything from the JKS ... simply adding the crt worked and now it shows PrivateKeyEntry